# How to get rails excel export to work on filtered index, currently exports entire list of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My app exports a list of all foo objects even when the display is set to only show some foos.  To the best of my knowledge, I'm setting the array of foos to export based on which view the user is looking at.  I can't figure out why the page is displaying the appropriate `@foos` but not exporting the appropriate `@foos_for_xls`.

I've got this call from my index:

```
<%= link_to "Export to Excel", foos_path(format: "xls"), :class => "btn btn-primary pull-right" %>
```

It works fine unless I filter on the list by passing in a param from a dropdown navbar button like:

```
<li><%= link_to "SPACE" , :action => :index, :location_id => 2 %></li>
```

That controller's index and respond_to look like:

```
def index
        @foos = Foo.order(:name)

      if params[:location_id]       
        @foos = @foos.order(:name).by_location(params[:location_id]).search(params[:search])
        @foos_for_xls_loc = @cabinets
      else
        @foos_for_xls = @foos
      end

    @foos = @foos.page params[:page]

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @foos }
      if params[:location_code]
        format.csv { send_data @foos_for_xls_loc.to_csv }
        format.xls { send_data @foos_for_xls_loc.to_csv(col_sep: "\t") }
      else
        format.csv { send_data @foos_for_xls.to_csv }
        format.xls { send_data @foos_for_xls.to_csv(col_sep: "\t") }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here's the model method that does the filtering:

```
def self.by_loc(location_id)
    if location_id
      joins(:location).where("location.id = ?", location_id)
    else
      scoped
    end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this solution works for me, but the user need first make the search and after export to excel, because it takes the params in URL to make the request to export.

```
= link_to "Export", orders_path(request.parameters.merge({format: :xlsx})), class: 'btn btn-success'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue and found the solution.  You can refer to this link for the solution :
[I want to export searched data to excel file in rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456568/i-want-to-export-searched-data-to-excel-file-in-rails-app)

Comment: You forgot the link in your post.