# I want to export searched data to excel file in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, export-to-excel

I have implemented search option in my project. It searches records on basis of many fields given by user And then displays record according to it. Now I want those filtered records to be exported as excel. How can I do that?

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel

Comment: I have seen this video. Actually my problem is that when I click on download as xls it returns me all the records as xls  format. While I want that it should return only those records which are filtered and are displayen in the table

Comment: Use format.xls response for your search action, instead of index action.

Comment: @Geordee : Can you give me example

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to merge the search parameters. The parameter merging allows you to reuse whatever parameters were passed in the page and apply the xls format. Example below.

```
=link_to 'Export', users_path(request.parameters.merge({:format => :xls}))
```

Answer (score 1):

(**tested on Rails 5.0**)

In my case, adding `download: 'projects.xlsx'` solved my problem!

```
<%= link_to 'Export', 
    projects_path(request.parameters.merge({format: :xlsx})), 
    download: 'projects.xlsx' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a method where I can send params in download link.
So after the user submits the form and result is displayed url contains all the params of the form. So what I have done is that I have taken the current url(which contains all the search params) and append the format as xls to it. Example is given below -

This solution works fine for me